# How do I get the values of a parsed query string in python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
querystring = cgi.parse_qs(decrypted_qs)

self.response.out.write(querystring) #output: {'param2': ['v2'], 'param1': ['v1']}

self.response.out.write(querystring.param2) #AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'param2'
```

The original dict: `{'param1': 'v1', 'param2': 'v2'}`

So why isn't the second one working, what's the right way to access the values?

I'm running Python 2.5.2 on App Engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python dicts don't work like JavaScript dicts.  You need to use it the same way you access elements in a list:

```
querystring['param2']
```

Comment: Oh well that was fast. How'd I miss that? :P

Answer (score 0):

Don't attempt to extract query string parameters yourself in the first place - use your framework. If you're using webapp, you can access query string parameters through the dict `self.request.GET`.

Comment: @Wooble I'll leave mine, since it's impossible to tell that from the question, and others may arrive here with the same query.